# Microsoft Edge F12 and Microsoft Edge Dev Tools Preview crashes

Tags: excel, typescript, office-js, microsoft-edge, add-in

The Microsoft Edge F12 tool and the Microsoft Edge Dev Tool Preview app crash on opening. This problem does not occur on same website using new Microsoft Edge Chromium version.

**I am writing this question with the intent on self answering it, after 7 lost hours of debugging**

I am developing an Excel Add-in using the new Microsoft Edge WebView for office-addins, which just rolled out, and replaces IE11 as the embedded IFrame in Excel with Edge (see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/). After this last month roll out, the problem presented.

The crash is predictable, occurs after 5 seconds after activating the tool. It occurs when using F12 tools in Edge browser, and when using the standalone Dev Tools Preview to remote connect to the Edge browser running in MS Excel.

(I won't put app event logs because I have already solved it)

Answer (score 1):

This is a Microsoft bug, not a coding bug.

It always occurs when using Typescript and defining a multidimensional array with only one element, and only in an async function

```
async myFunc(){
  let x:number[][] = [[9]]; //Edge F12 tool will crash simply by having this line
}
```

The problem does not occur in non async functions, and does not occur if the variable is defined as a class member. It does not occur if more than one element is defined. Workaround is to define the variable as private class member

```
public x:number[][] = [[9]]; //ok as member variable

let x:number[][] = [[9,2]]; //ok - even in async function
```

---

For those reading this who rightly ask "*why would you want to define a multidimensional array with only 1 element*". It is because MS Excel is a 2D array, and to set the value of cells the Excel API expects two dimensional arrays Excel.Range.values[][] =any[][]. So if you want to set the value of only one cell, you must supply a multidimensional array with only one value.

NB. I have not raised the bug with Microsoft as they are no longer supporting the Microsoft Edge Dev Tools preview, instead focusing on rolling out the Edge Chromium version, thus deprecating these tools. The problem does not occur in the Edge Chromium developer release, but I have no idea when Edge Chromium will be rolled out as the embedded browser in Excel (we only just left IE11 behind last month)

Answer (score 0):

@JimbobTheSailor
Thank you for taking the time to report the issue and also coming back to provide the possible cause of the issue.

I know you have already spent a bunch of time on this issue, but I was hoping you could provide an example code file, or even npm package, that will cause the issue? I went and added your code and attempted to reproduce the issue, but I could not. [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/LouMM/SO56695936)! By providing the entire package, or example, I can also see the different versions of TypeScript and other dependencies. You could also just list them here as well.

If possible, and don't mind grabbing it, could you provide the version of Windows you are using? START | RUN | WINVER . Also, the version of the DevTools Preview? Example:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsPreview_18.924.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

To run my sample all you have to do is:

```
npm install
npm run build:dev
npm start
```

...or the yarn equivalent.

This will build, sideload the app, and boot Excel.

Comment: Windows 10 version 1903, Office 365 ver 1906, build 1137.20230 - which means Microsoft Edge is the embedded IFrame. Edge Dev tools preview is the latest version on the Microsoft Store, release date 3/2/2018. Angular 8.0.0,  Typescript 3.4.5, Office-js 1.0.12.  I find the Edge Dev Tools Preview very unstable. It crashes often. When my code has no bugs, it runs fund. When it has bugs it constantly crashes- but it is when I have bugs that i need it!  Very much looking forward to Microsoft putting Edge chromium in Excel

Comment: @JimbobTheSailor have you tried switching off the performance monitors within Office? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization has some info. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/657#issuecomment-525087641 should help you find the registry key to change. Hope this helps!